# SQL and Regex | check url path

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to show in SQL only the URL that have a path, for example:

> stackoverflow.com/ - no path
>
> stackoverflow.com/abc.html - no path
>
> stackoverflow.com/abc- path
>
> stackoverflow.com/abc/bla/- path

now in regex the answer is `\/\w+$`

I know regex is not working well with SQL, so i don't know how could i check
URL.

this is what i tried:

```
select * from sites where url like '\/\w+$'
```

Comment: What kind database did you use, MySQL,MSSQL,oracle?

Comment: SQL server 2014

Comment: Afaik the `like` operator uses [*Wildcards*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), not *Regex*

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong; `stackoverflow.com/abc` is not a path as `abc` is a file.

Answer (score 1):

This checks if URL contains two slashes:

```
SELECT *
FROM testdata
WHERE url LIKE '%/%/%'
```

Technically speaking, the URLs `stackoverflow.com/abc.html` and `stackoverflow.com/abc` are identical, where you have a hostname and a filename. The above example will only match `stackoverflow.com/abc/bla/`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql):

```
WITH cte(p) AS (
    SELECT 'stackoverflow.com/' 
    UNION SELECT 'stackoverflow.com/abc.html' 
    UNION SELECT 'stackoverflow.com/abc'
    UNION SELECT 'stackoverflow.com/abc/bla'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(p)) < CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(p));
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/HPVDY55425)**